# Updating via WMI

Tags: c#, wmi, wmi-query

I need an example of an update query using WMI. I have searched but I couldn´t find anything.

Can anyone paste some sample code if possible?

Thanks.

Comment: WMI queries ar SQL like queries, so it should not be so difficult

Comment: Yes, I know this, but i mean some code where i can see how to send the query to the WMI. Sorry for my english

Comment: "c sharp wmi example" @ google and you will get plenty of examples ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Process Information and Notifications using WMI](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12138/Process-Information-and-Notifications-using-WMI) is an example of WMI.

The WMI Query Language (WQL) is read-only. There are no keywords such as `INSERT` or `UPDATE`.  You cannot modify the WMI objects.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [WMI Code Creator](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=2cc30a64-ea15-4661-8da4-55bbc145c30e&displaylang=en)